# OpenCV VideoCapture object for image stream from camera

Tags: java, windows, opencv, webcam

When I try to capture image from my webcam, OpenCV throws an exception in following statement:

```
new org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture(0);
```

It says “unknown exception” of type java.lang.Exception. I wonder how to fix this error.

Comment: Try changing the device ID from 0 to 1, 2, etc, until it starts working. Also, it might be silly to mention it, but is your camera available at the moment you're testing your code? If it is, and the changes in device ID are not helping, change the way you're creating the video capture, by doing it like it's suggested in [the official example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html)

Comment: Well, parameter change did not work. According to OpenCV Java documentation, we need to send parameter 0 to use default camera.